# Using setTimeout with strings triggers unsafe-eval alert

Tags: javascript, settimeout, eval

Here is the example how it appear in Chrome dev tools:

```
setTimeout(console.log(`String`), 100);
```

String Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source ofscript in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src'self' 'unsafe-inline' https:".

What does this alert means and what is the security concern of using setTimeout with strings?

Comment: Which browser are use and which OS?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src#unsafe_eval_expressions

Comment: It means you configured your server in such a way that it delivers a CSP header that forbids script from source `unsafe-eval` which includes strings. There is no point in using strings anyway, though - why would you need them? You can simply pass an (arrow) function.

Comment: Thanks for looking into my inquiry. Do you mind to elaborate in more simple terms as I am a beginner? What do you mean by server configuration while using Chrome Dev Tools console? What is CSP header? Why there is no point in using strings if all I need is to console log a string and why arrow function is the preferred way? Thanks!

Comment: "*what is the security concern of using setTimeout with strings?*" - do you understand what the security concern of using `eval` is?

Comment: I believe it is because of the malicious code can be passed instead of a string and the program will execute it and thus the breach will occur. But how is the eval related to setTimeout? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `setTimeout` wrong.

When you append parens after a function  in JS, it immediately calls the function, and "replaces" the expression with the *return value* of that function.

But, with `setTimeout`, you *don't* want to call that function, you want `setTimeout` to call it! To do that, you *give* the function to `setTimeout` without calling it, and `setTimeout` will call it internally for you when the timer goes off.

But your code does call the function, `console.log`, and only gives its return value (`undefined`) to `setTimeout`. `setTimeout` doesn't throw an error though - it has an old "feature" that if you pass a string to it, it evaluates it as if you used `eval`.

`undefined` is not a string, but neither is it a function, so when the timer expires, `setTimeout` will cast it to a string (`"undefined"`) and try to `eval` it. That's why you get the warning.

---

You can fix this by passing your function to `setTimeout` "the good way": wrap your call into another function. This way, your outer function will call `console.log` when *it* is called, so you can pass that to `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(() => console.log(`String`), 100);
```

Comment: Hi FZs, thanks for your breakdown. Maybe I'm starting to get it. So is eval a part of setTimeout? Also, isn't the console.log(`String`) return value is the string itself, why you're saying it is undefined? And yes, there is no error, just a warning. I am just trying to understand the meaning of that warning. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I also believe that I missed the fact that console.log is a function and now I see why wrapper arrow function inside setTimeout makes so much sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Novigda Yes, that eval-ish thing is built into *browsers'* `setTimeout` (Node.js doesn't have that though, for example). `console.log()` always *returns* `undefined` while *displaying* the string you passed in.